# Shade Matrix Plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to create a shade plot in R, like the ones you can make in PRIMER like this one: [Shade plot made in PRIMER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNyFj.png)

Are there any packages or functions that could do this in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are looking for a `geom_tile` from the `ggplot2` package.

**Example Data**

```
library(tidyverse)

df  <- structure(list(`Sampling Location` = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "C", "C", "C"), Taxa = c("X", "Y", "Z", "X", "Y", "Z", "X", 
"Y", "Z"), value = c(1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.8, 0.4, 0, 0.6, 0, 0.1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Plot**

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = `Sampling Location`,  y = Taxa,
                fill = value)) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  labs(title = "Untransformed")
```

**Plot**
[image]